# HTML fix div when scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way to make a div stay fixed when the page has scrolled a certain way down?

I know its a bit vague, but I couldn't think of any other way of explaining it. I'm guessing a script would be needed and would look something like this:

```
if y-position of div = 75 then
    div css position = "fixed";
end if
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery:

```
$('body').bind('scroll', function(){
    var div = $('div'),
        div_pos = div.offset().top;

    if(div_pos >= 75) div.css('position','fixed');
});
```